# String parsing in Python with various unique cases

Tags: python, string, parsing

My goal is to convert a string into a dictionary. Here's how it looks like:

```
[exploit] => 1
[hits] => 1
[completed] => 1
[is_malware] => 1
[summary] => 26.0@13965: suspicious.warning: object contains JavaScript
76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using eval
76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using String.fromCharCode

[severity] => 4
[engine] => 60
```

So I've tried several ways to do this, first attempt was to `split` at `\n`, but I encountered the problem that for [summary], the contents are split so that didn't work. Then my second attempt was `split` at `=>` however I encountered the problem that once I split at => it won't know that it has to split at `\n` for the next key. Essentially it should look like this in the end
    { exploit:1, hits:1, completed:1....} so on so forth

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to parse the text:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\[([^]]+)\] => (.*?)(?=\n\[|$)', s, re.S)
[('exploit', '1'), ('hits', '1'), ('completed', '1'), ('is_malware', '1'), ('summary', '26.0@13965: suspicious.warning: object contains JavaScript\n76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using eval\n76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using String.fromCharCode\n'), ('severity', '4'), ('engine', '60')]
```

You can put these values into a dictionary by calling `dict`.

```
>>> dict(re.findall('\[([^]]+)\] => (.*?)(?=\n\[|$)', s, re.S))
{'engine': '60', 'hits': '1', 'severity': '4', 'is_malware': '1', 'summary': '26.0@13965: suspicious.warning: object contains JavaScript\n76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using eval\n76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using String.fromCharCode\n', 'exploit': '1', 'completed': '1'}
```

Comment: this doesn't match the last entry `[engine]`

Comment: yeah, it's a tricky one, I wouldn't bother sticking this in a silver-bullet regex - especially if the content is subject to change.

Comment: I have a slight problem though. Whilst running the code I only get this as result: [('engine', '60')] and everything else vanishes.

Comment: @Shelby.S then instead of showing us the characters you see, show us the output of `repr(your_total_string)`,  (repr() shows all hidden newline etc characters that could be preventing is from suggesting a decent regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
total_string = """\
[exploit] => 1
[hits] => 1
[completed] => 1
[is_malware] => 1
[summary] => 26.0@13965: suspicious.warning: object contains JavaScript
76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using eval
76.0@14467: suspicious.obfuscation using String.fromCharCode

[severity] => 4
[engine] => 60
"""

import re

pattern_RE = '\[([^]]+)\] => (.*?)(?=\n\[|$)'
report_dict = dict(re.findall(pattern_RE, total_string, re.S))

for k, v in report_dict.items():
    print('[{}]: {}'.format(k, v))

print(report_dict)
```

right now what you are showing us is this, but there could be newlines and carriage returns hidden. The regex seems ok for what we can see.

```
{   'engine': '60', 
    'hits': '1', 
    'severity': '4', 
    'is_malware': '1', 
    'summary': '(all three captured)',
    'exploit': '1', 
    'completed': '1'
}
```

So if the regex isn't catching this, then the repr() of total_string must be slightly different to what you pasted ( maybe a trailing newline, or something)